# Eclipse with Haskell plugin errors

Tags: eclipse, haskell

Following the instructions from this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Haskell-A-Project-Based-Approach/dp/1430262508/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1392746814&sr=8-2&keywords=haskell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430262508)

I have Eclipse Kepler on Mac OS X Maverick. On installation within Eclipse, I get these errors on installation:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Graphalyze-0.14.0.2 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
SourceGraph-0.7.0.5 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
conduit-1.0.15 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to install.
http-client-conduit-0.2.0.1 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
http-conduit-2.0.0.6 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
lifted-base-0.2.2.0 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
mmorph-1.0.2 failed while unpacking the package. The exception was:
user error (data is not in tar format)
monad-control-0.3.2.3 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to
install.
pandoc-1.12.3.3 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to install.
resourcet-0.4.10 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to install.
text-stream-decode-0.1.0.3 failed while unpacking the package. The exception
was:
user error (data is not in tar format)
transformers-base-0.4.1 failed while unpacking the package. The exception was:
user error (data is not in tar format)
yaml-0.8.7.2 depends on transformers-base-0.4.1 which failed to install.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to install `transformers-base-0.4.1` from cabal using `cabal install transformers-base`?

Comment: Data not in tar format is something to do with cabal being broken. Try downloading and installing manually.